# plugin-install.php page randomly injected into Wordpress dashboard sections

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having an incredibly strange error with my WP Dashboard here's what happened.

1. I manually installed a plugin called [Widget Context](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/)
2. I began seeing the error shown below
3. I tried deleting the plugin and got an error (the error was just a giant text wall seemingly of gibberish, not an actual error code).
4. I tried deleting the plugin again, and it worked.

However now I am still getting the same error. The the plugin-install.php page is getting injected all over my WP Dashboard in various places. Additionally, I cannot search for any plugins either.

Has anyone encountered this or knows of a way to perhaps troubleshoot it? Clearing caches, etc?

Things I have tried:

- Deleting any artifacts left behind from the plugin (there were none so it appears to have deleted successfully)
- re-installing wordpress via the updates menu
- Emptying my browser cache

[image]

Comment: Do you have a backup of your files and database pre change?

Comment: Presumably yes, but this site is hosted on a larger internal network so I'll have to go though IT to confirm. 

Now the site appears to not respond, or rather it is constantly getting a loading spinner but not necessarily throwing a no response error..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like restarting the service server-side fixed the error.